# Which logistic regression python solvers would suit on my project?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I use Sklearn to analyse my csv file and export it to a .PKL file (a file created by pickle). I often get this message:

```
C:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_logistic.py:765: ConvergenceWarning: lbfgs failed to converge (status=1):
STOP: TOTAL NO. of ITERATIONS REACHED LIMIT.

Increase the number of iterations (max_iter) or scale the data as shown in:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html
Please also refer to the documentation for alternative solver options:
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#logistic-regression
  extra_warning_msg=_LOGISTIC_SOLVER_CONVERGENCE_MSG)
```

I have already increased the max_iter. Now I wanted to change my solver as well to check if this converges faster. On this [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) there are different solver.

I have tried all of them and they all work. Except for `lbfgs` and `liblinear` I get the upper error message. With `saga` and `sag` I get no error message, but the conversion takes a long time.

My csv file already has about 68MB. It has over 37000 rows and 63 columns.
`Name: class, Length: 37563, dtype: object`

Which of the available solvers would be suitable for me?

Comment: Have you standarized your data?

Comment: No, I did not standarized my data. Do I have to do this? Do you mean by standardized by returning a normalized value?

Comment: If your features have very different scales, it can help to converge faster. Use `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler`

Comment: @DiegoPalacios Im already using `sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler`  to Construct a Pipeline from the given estimators `sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline`.